# Getting Junk values from rest webservice via restTemplate in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, resttemplate

I am trying to call a restful web-service from a Java application but it is returning junk values(笀∀匀戀搀䐀愀琀伀甀琀∀㨀笀∀愀瀀氀䤀渀昀䔀挀漀∀㨀笀∀愀瀀氀). The service is returning correct Json if we call from the `Postman` application.
Below is the code I am using.

```
String res = String.valueOf(restTemplate.postForObject(<service url>, entity, String.class)).toString();
```

Please suggest.

Comment: With the exception of the upside down letter A these are all Chinese characters (and I just guess the traditional version used in Hong Kong and Taiwan, not Mainland China). If I remove the non-Chinese characters, baidu translation yields something about love - and google translate about love and dope (no typo, not hope). Is there someone trying to send you a message? :-D

Comment: Ok, 笀∀匀戀搀䐀愀琀伀甀琀∀㨀笀∀愀瀀氀䤀渀昀䔀挀漀∀㨀笀∀愀瀀氀 is junk – but what did you expect instead?

Comment: this is mojibake, make sure charset is specified as UTF-8. Otherwise it gets sent as UTF-16

Answer (score 0):

Use `postForEntity` method like below:

```
ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(<service url> , entity , String.class);
String body = result.getBody();
```

Comment: Below code is not helping, still getting those charaters.                      
       ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(<service url> , entity , String.class);
String body = result.getBody();